# Как задать версию программы Android?

Tags: android, java

Для маркета нужно задать, что версия программы не 1,0, а 1,1 как это сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: в манифесте поменять

**UPD1** версию и версию кода

Comment: А точней? Куда писать? Что?

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.blabla"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.1.1" >

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html

Очень много интересного пишут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В манифесте есть 2 атрибута имеющих отношение к версии `android:versionCode` и `android:versionName`.

- `android:versionCode` - целое число от него всего лишь требуется, чтобы от версии к версии он увеличивался. Используется для обновлений. То есть когда выставляете новую версию то если указать versionCode больше чем предыдущую то прога будет обновляться иначе нет.
- `android:versionName` - строчное обозначение версии. Используется только для того, чтобы  отобразить в самой проге или в маркете версию программы

В коде версию проги можно получить так (например, чтобы отобразить в менюшке About/О программе:

```
String versionName=context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
```

Comment: кто будет этим заниматься, обращайте внимания, что при выкладывании приложения надо менять оба значения

Comment: Я обычно версию приложения привязываю к номеру версии даваемой Subversion/Git/CVS - очень удобно